# How to store json array data into mysql database in JAVA?

Tags: java, json

I want to store the following JSON Array into MySql Database

My Requirement is to Synchronize the below data with MySql DB from an android Application.

```
[  
   {  
      "DATE":"Oct 15, 2015 7:09:23 AM",
      "LNG":"75.124",
      "LAT":"15.3647066",
      "IMEI":"2",
      "LOC":"Prabhat Colony"
   },
   {  
      "DATE":"Oct 15, 2015 7:09:41 AM",
      "LNG":"75.0078",
      "LAT":"15.4589233",
      "IMEI":"2",
      "LOC":"Hosayellapur"
   },
   {  
      "DATE":"Oct 15, 2015 7:15:56 AM",
      "LNG":"74.4977",
      "LAT":"15.849695",
      "IMEI":"2",
      "LOC":"Camp"
   },
   {  
      "DATE":"Oct 15, 2015 7:50:19 AM",
      "LNG":"77.209",
      "LAT":"28.6139383",
      "IMEI":"2",
      "LOC":"Rajpath Area"
   },
   {  
      "DATE":"Oct 15, 2015 7:50:41 AM",
      "LNG":"77.391",
      "LAT":"28.535515",
      "IMEI":"2",
      "LOC":"Sector - 106"
   },
   {  
      "DATE":"Oct 15, 2015 8:07:25 AM",
      "LNG":"77.391",
      "LAT":"28.535515",
      "IMEI":"2",
      "LOC":"Sector - 106"
   },
   {  
      "DATE":"Oct 15, 2015 8:20:26 AM",
      "LNG":"77.391",
      "LAT":"28.535515",
      "IMEI":"2",
      "LOC":"Sector - 106"
   }
]
```

Can anyone please guide me on which is the best way to store JSON values to mysql Database?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object containing your attributes, and then deserialize your json to get an array of your object.

Then, you can then use JPA or another method to store your object in the database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unmarshal the steam into Predefined DTO classes. You can use GSon. Gson is an open source Java library to serialize and deserialize Java objects to (and from) JSON.

   ```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ClassName className = gson.fromJson(data, ClassName.class);
   ```

2.Use ORM such as hibernate to store Object in relational database.